# Magento2.0 Server requirements - Need Guidance

Tags: magento2

We are using Magento2 for one of our projects. On our site there are approximately 2000 customers and around 3000 products right now. We are using Magento CE V 2.0.7.

It seems that our website is slow. Magento2 takes around 6 seconds to process the first byte.

According to GTMatrix, our Page Speed is 61%. Don't know why the site is slow.
We have to improve our page speed and we already followed some instructions from GTMatrix.

Few things about the server configuration:

- AWS t2.large instance.
- 8GB RAM
- 2vCPU
- Server is  VPS.

Is this configuration sufficient for Magento 2? Or does Magento need some more configuration?

Is it possible that because of this it affects on Page Speed & Website Performance?

Comment: It's slow because it's Magento... you'll probably want an m4.xlarge for that (depending on traffic) with a Redis caching server. Moving from bespoke code to Magento 1.9 previously we had to increase server capacity tenfold and install a Full Page Cache - Magento is a beast.

Answer (score 1):

**8GB RAM and 2CPU** on **AWS VPS** should be more than enough to run Magento 2 in good conditions and at a reasonable speed. See here official documentation about this: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html

Magento 2 needs though quite a lot of configuration in order to be fast. Think about advanced cache options such as ***Memcached, Varnish and Redis***.

We are using since more than a year now [**Cloudways**](https://www.cloudways.com/en/?id=105056) because of their integrated solutions with all those options included plus one-click-install, staging automation, CDN, free migration and 24x7 Live chat support. On a Digital Ocean VPS with 8GB RAM which is slower than an AWS VPS with same RAM we are getting quite good load times on Magento 2.2 websites template based or custom made.

You must of course also go through all possible frontend speed optimisation like:

- ***merge and minify*** all CSS and JS files.
- optimise all ***image sizes***.
- use ***CDN*** if needed.
- **Gzip** compression

See more details about Magento frontend optimization [HERE](https://canonicalized.com/magento-speed-optimization/?section=http2-cdn).

Using the latest version **Magento CE 2.3** will definitly help as versions 2.0.x had a lot of speed related issues.

Comment: To add to the answer, Varnish and Redis is supported by Magento, making it easier to configure along with Magento.